# Highlighting a cell in Excel when it has a specific word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm looking the formula or conditional formatting option in the excel to highlight a particular `cell` when it contains a specific word.

For example:

- When `cell` contains *"Car"* it should highlight the `cell` in *Red*.
- When it contains *"Truck"* `cell` should higlight in *Yellow*.
- When it contains *"Wagon"* should higlight in *Green*.
- When in contains *all the three* or *any two mentioned words* in one `cell` should highlight in colour *Amber*.

I know in conditional formatting there is a option to do it, but unfortunately same didn't work when same `cell` have different key words in a same `cell` i.e if `cell` have both *Car* and *Wagon*.

The `cell` will contain a string of words eg. *"Martin has a Car & Truck in his home"* - so in this case the excel should identify the *"Car"* and *"Truck"* word in the `cell` and highlight the `cell` accordingly. In this case it should be *Amber* colour.

Is there some solution for this?

Comment: You must first define a unique background colour for each of the **7** unique possibilities.

Comment: What color should *'Carlton has a truck'* be?

Comment: I think you could do a conditional formatting - you'll have to be kind of clever though, I'm trying to but can't quite get it.  But, FYI, here's what I'm starting with.  I'm using a formula to determine if the cell has "Car", "Truck", or both.  You can feather the "wagon" in if you can get it working.  Here's what I have as my conditional format: `IF(ISERROR(AND(SEARCH("Car",B17206),SEARCH("Truck",B17206))>1),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Car",B17206))>0,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("truck",B17206)>0),"Car","Truck")),"Both")="Both"`.  Just add two more rules, changing that `="Both"`, to `="Car"` and `="Truck"`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it going with Conditional Formatting.  What I did was basically string together some `If(Iserror(...` statements to return "Car", "Truck", "Both".  You can feather in the "Wagon" (or let me know more information and I can work it in).

Highlight your a cell that you want to color, and enter these formulas (note, in my example, you want to replace `B17206`).  Each formula will be its own conditional formatting, set to how you want it

```
=IF(ISERROR(AND(SEARCH("Car",B17206),SEARCH("Truck",B17206))>1),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Car",B17206))>0,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("truck",B17206)>0),"Car","Truck")),"Both")="Truck"

=IF(ISERROR(AND(SEARCH("Car",B17206),SEARCH("Truck",B17206))>1),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Car",B17206))>0,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("truck",B17206)>0),"Car","Truck")),"Both")="Car"

=IF(ISERROR(AND(SEARCH("Car",B17206),SEARCH("Truck",B17206))>1),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Car",B17206))>0,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("truck",B17206)>0),"Car","Truck")),"Both")="Both"
```

I used those and correctly get this (yellow is for "Both", Red is for "Car", and Green is for "Truck"):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, in my real file I have 40 words which needs to be tag under one colour. Will that be possibly?

Comment: @pratheeshrajan - probably, yes! I'll have a think.  It may be Monday before I get back to you, but I'll check it out.